# Sound messed up after forced Windows 8.1 update?

Tags: windows, audio

So I was forced to update to Windows 8.1 this morning, and I noticed that my sound is weird now.

I can only hear sounds from the window or tab that's open, and nothing else (except Spotify, which might be taking priority)

I have no idea what's causing this or how to fix it.

Any ideas?
I'll provide screenshots of anything you need.

It's a Realtek High Definition Audio thing, by the way.

Comment: post more details about your used hardware. Does reinstalling the audio driver fixes it?

Comment: Post updated. Also, I'm trying that now.

Comment: Windows 8.1 changed how sound is handled. By tabs I assume you mean a browser tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My OS update included the dumb Realtek Audio driver that I forgot about removing when I first got the computer.

I removed it and now everything works fine.

Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling the update if it was just one - this may reinstate your sound abilities.  A "system restore" may be the easiest way to do this if there are multiple updates to uninstall.

Try reinstalling your sound drivers - this could get you working again.

Run an AV/Malware/Spyware scan - this wouldn;t be the first time I've seen time-delayed virus coinside with windows updates - especially if the virus is triggered at reboot and the machine hasn't been restarted in a while.

Check whether the problem happens in safe mode as well as normal windows mode.

Comment: It was a huge update TO Windows 8.1 from Windows 8. I'll try reinstalling my audio driver. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry that I didn't say that it was an update TO Windows 8.1.

Comment: Yeah a system restore point isn't relevant and cannot be used in a case like this

Comment: My bad Cody... I read it as installing windows 8.1 updates.. not an OS upgrade.

Comment: All good @Fazer87 

Also, this has been solved. With the OS update, it installed the dumb Realtek driver, so I removed it and now it works just as it used to.